# Is there a BigInteger class in PHP?

Tags: php, biginteger

Is there a BigInteger class in PHP? If so, how do I access it or use it?

Comment: Please rephrase the question; if not in English, use PHP code. What is the problem you want to solve?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hopefully helpfull links :

- http://php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php

**EDIT:   Math_BigInteger**

Example from http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/documentation/math.html :

Implements an arbitrary precision integer arithmetic library. Uses gmp or bcmath, if available, and an internal implementation, otherwise.

```
<?php
    include('Math/BigInteger.php');

    $a = new Math_BigInteger(2);
    $b = new Math_BigInteger(3);

    $c = $a->add($b);

    echo $c->toString(); // outputs 5
?>
```

Answer (score 8):

Even though this question is old, it comes up as first result when Googling for `BigInteger PHP`, so for anyone interested, I open-sourced a library called [Brick\Math](https://github.com/brick/math) offering `BigInteger`, `BigDecimal` and `BigRational` classes.

---

### Usage

```php
use Brick\Math\BigInteger;
use Brick\Math\RoundingMode;
```

Addition:

```php
echo BigInteger::of('9999999999999999999999999')->plus(1);
// 10000000000000000000000000
```

Subtraction:

```php
echo BigInteger::of('10000000000000000000000000')->minus(1);
// 9999999999999999999999999
```

Multiplication:

```php
echo BigInteger::of('3333333333333333333333333')->multipliedBy(11);
// 36666666666666666666666663
```

Division:

```php
echo BigInteger::of('1000000000000000000000')->dividedBy(3, RoundingMode::UP);
// 333333333333333333334
```

Exponentiation:

```php
echo BigInteger::of(11)->power(50);
// 11739085287969531650666649599035831993898213898723001
```

You can easily chain method calls:

```php
echo BigInteger::of(3)->multipliedBy(7)->minus(1)->dividedBy(10);
```

---

### Installation

Just install with [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) and you're done:

```php
composer require brick/math
```

The library automatically uses the [GMP](https://php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) and [BCMath](https://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) extensions when available, to speed up calculations, but will also work without them thanks to a pure PHP implementation.