# PHP calculating real big/large numbers shows wrong result

Tags: php

According to this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_numbers#RSA-100):

> 37975227936943673922808872755445627854565536638199
> × 40094690950920881030683735292761468389214899724061

Result should be:

> 1522605027922533360535618378132637429718068114961380688657908494580122963258952897654000350692006139

I tested:

```
<?php
$a = '37975227936943673922808872755445627854565536638199';
$b = '40094690950920881030683735292761468389214899724061';

echo "A: ".$a."\n";
echo "B: ".$b."\n";

$c = $a * $b; 

echo "Result:\n".number_format($c, 0, '', '')."\n";
echo "Expected: \n1522605027922533360535618378132637429718068114961380688657908494580122963258952897654000350692006139";
?>
```

And I got result:

> A: 37975227936943673922808872755445627854565536638199
> B: 40094690950920881030683735292761468389214899724061
>
> Result:
> 1522605027922533518260457400714874678658400574018662242210976145948887793656784833912073618129420288
>
> Expected:
> 1522605027922533360535618378132637429718068114961380688657908494580122963258952897654000350692006139

Why does PHP show wrong result?

Is there a way to get correct result?

Comment: Why do you need this result at all?

Comment: Read more about `PHP_INT_MAX`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35169951/php-gives-incorrect-results-when-formatting-long-numbers

Comment: @AksenP Logic: 2+2 should NOT be 3 or 5. If you don't understand the question then why downvote and comment questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some say PHP can't handle such large numbers. But I still don't understand the result PHP outputs seems to be large enough to me, but are NOT correct.

> Is there a way to get correct results?

**Yes**, for PHP 1 line solution (using Python3):

```
echo exec('python3 -c "print('.$a.' * '.$b.')"');
```

Results as expected:

> 1522605027922533360535618378132637429718068114961380688657908494580122963258952897654000350692006139

Comment: The PHP result matches the result of multiplication when using the double-precision floating point.

Answer (score 0):

There are php functions to perform mathematical functions on numbers which are saved as strings:

have a look at [this function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcmul.php)