# Calculate factorial for 999

Tags: php

I got a problem to solve. I need write a PHP scipt to calculate a factorial for a number from 1 to 1000, what seems easy, by it also says that "but if it gives INF for 999, your algorithm is wrong". I'm confused.

Comment: what did you try so far ? please post

Comment: See perhaps [Is there a BigInteger class for PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427020/is-there-a-biginteger-class-in-php)

Comment: because the PHP couldn't handle the number with that much number of digits,

Answer (score 2):

There is function in php to do this

```
<?php

$fact = gmp_fact(999); // 999 * 998 * 997, ... etc
echo gmp_strval($fact)
?>
```

This returns the factorial , for reference http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-fact.php