# Permutation generator php/java Script

Tags: java, php, combinations, permutation

I have 13 football matches with a possible results of Home Win , Draw , Away win. One has to predict all 13 games for a single bet. I have been trying to generate a script that can compute all possible bet combinations, mathematically, the number of possible matches is 3^13.

So far what I have is this in PHP;

```
    $count  = 1;
    $total_rows     = 13;
    $total_level    = 13;
    $total_cols     = 3;
    $total_global   = 3;

    $active_rows    = 0;
    $active_cols    = 0;
    $active_levels  = 0;
    $active_global  = 0;

    $betArray   = array();

    $aciveChoice[$total_rows]   = 0;
    $globalChoice[$total_level] = 0;

    while($active_rows < $total_rows){
        while($active_cols < $total_cols){

            while($active_global < $total_global){
                while($active_levels < $total_level){
                    echo $active_rows.' - '.$active_levels.': Select:'.$active_cols.' - '.$active_global.'<br/>';
                    $active_levels++;
                }
                echo $count++.'<br /><br /><br />';
                $active_levels  = 0;
                $active_global++;                       
            }

            $active_global = 0;
            $active_cols++;
        }
        $active_cols    = 0;
        $active_rows++; 
        }   
    }
```

My script is not giving all possible combinations. Any ideas on how to tackle this will be appreciated.

Comment: 13^3? No, 3^13! Are you sure you want 1594323 rows on your web page?

Comment: @Amadan This is for analysis purpose and not for display.

Comment: Well, what do you want to do with 1594323 results? stuff them in a list? call a callback? Your code doesn't really give me a hint...

Comment: @Amadan for testing I am obviously not using 13. I am using 4 to test. I want to get the script right first then I will organize my code thereafter. The purpose of this is to create a decision support system for users based on history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$matches = 13;
$outcomes = 3;
$possibilities = $outcomes ** $matches;

for ($count = 0; $count < $possibilities; $count++) {
  echo str_pad(base_convert($count, 10, 3), $matches, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)."\n";
}
```

This will print a number of 13-character strings, with three different possibilities for each character. (It is up to you to decide how to allocate meanings; I'd probably use `1` for Team1 win, `2` for Team2 win, `0` for draw.)

This will fail if you make the numbers too large, since `base_convert` works through `float`, apparently. There are [ways around it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427020/is-there-a-biginteger-class-in-php), but if you're exploring that many possibilities you might have other problems :P

Comment: This is perfect @Amadan . Exactly what I wanted