# Can not get correct result with addition of Bigint number with 1

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating admissions table in which stud_id column is unsigned bigint(250).
I am apply query "alter table admission AUTO_INCREMENT = 2001923456789000;
and in php coding i am fetching last index and adding 1 into it but i get wrong result plz give solution. result in exponential format.

```
$sql="select MAX(id) from com_result"; 
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
if($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
     $id=$row[0]; 
     $stud_id1=$id+1; 
     echo "<input type='text' class='form-control' id='id' name='id' readonly value=".$stud_id1.">"; 
}
```

Comment: Do `echo PHP_INT_MAX;`. Check the value; data received from MySQL is overflowing. You will need to treat the number as `FLOAT` instead.

Comment: Also, this is a helpful answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2842548/2469308

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya i cant understand plz give brief

Comment: Edit the question and add relevant portions of the code where this is failing..

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya      $sql="select MAX(id) from com_result";
      $result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
       
      if($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
       {
        $id=$row[0];
        $stud_id1=$id+1;
           echo "<input type='text' class='form-control' id='id' name='id' readonly value=".$stud_id1.">"; 
       }

Comment: Do one thing: Just run this code separately `echo PHP_INT_MAX;` and give its output

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya  it gives 2147483647 but i want last_id of table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a BigInteger class in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427020/is-there-a-biginteger-class-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You are basically hitting the maximum limit for an integer value in PHP. As corroborated by you in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57024663/can-not-get-correct-result-with-addition-of-bigint-number-with-1?noredirect=1#comment100579556_57024663), the result of `echo PHP_INT_MAX;` on your server is: `2147483647`. (so, basically a 32-bit build of PHP).

One option is to rebuild the PHP on your server with a 64-bit version. Check this answer to understand the difference in integer range for different builds: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2842548/2469308

Now, in your current case, the number obtained from MySQL: `2001923456789000` is basically **overflowing**, since it is much higher than the maximum allowed value for an integer. That is why you are seeing wrong results, because once the limit is crossed, PHP would go backwards and start from the lowest allowed negative integer value, and so on.. (in cycles)

Now, in order to solve this issue in a 32-bit PHP, you will have to **explicitly typecast** the result obtained from MySQL to a `Float` datatype. **Floats can be used for integer values up to 2^53 + 1**.

Try the following:

```
if($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
     $id = (float)$row[0];  // <-- Typecasting to float
     $stud_id1 = $id + 1; 
     echo "<input type='text' class='form-control' id='id' name='id' readonly value=".$stud_id1.">"; 
}
```

Comment: it gives result like 2.019273413028E+17 and last index of table e.g 201927341302805001 and i want next number 201927341302805002

Comment: @user11708206 alternative solutions are available at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427020/is-there-a-biginteger-class-in-php