# For loop index gets retyped to float for large numbers

Tags: php, loops, largenumber

Consider this piece of code

```
$from = 486745904951485151;
$to = 486745904951485157;
$val = 486745904951485155;
for($i=$from; $i<=$to;$i++) {
   if($i == $val) {
       return true;
   }
}
```

I need to do 8 iterations total, but because the `$i` does not equal `486745904951485151` but rather it is retyped to float so `$i=4.8674590495149E+17` what I end up is getting infinite(-ish) loop, because the iteration condition never gets there to end the loop, because the $to is still integer.

I suppose this is some internal restriction of for iteration of php (docs were of no help), what is the best possible solution to handle the issue? I was thinking of didiving all the values by some factor of 10, so I artifically decrease the actual number, but was wondering if someone has some better idea to tackle this issue?

Additional info: yes, I am using 32bit PHP and version 5.6.3 (legacy app)

Comment: Are you usiing a 32bit or 64bit PHP? WHat version of PHP are you using

Comment: Try reading [Is there a biginteger class in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427020/is-there-a-biginteger-class-in-php)

Comment: I would say you are definitely using a 32bit PHP and `2147483647` is the largest Integer 32bit can hold. `echo PHP_INT_MAX;` to see

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks for the info, I suspected as much, but I am aware of the root of the issues, I was rather looking for a solution to the problem, if there is better one than mine

Comment: Look at the answer @adder links to. See if that will run in 32bit