# Check which flags are included inside a decimal

Tags: php, flags, bitmask

I need to check which hexadecimal flags are included in a certain decimal variable. At the moment the script just works for small decimals but I've some longer ones.

In the following example it shows me the right flags when I check the flags inside `$decimal2`, but it doesn't work with `$decimal`.

I don't know the reason for this behaviour and what has to be changed.

This is the [example demo](https://3v4l.org/1gGIq).

```
$decimal = 613090029426844e18; // doesn't work
$decimal2 = 64; //works

const FLAG_1 = 0x1;
const FLAG_2 = 0x2; 
const FLAG_3 = 0x4;
const FLAG_4 = 0x4;
const FLAG_5 = 0x32;
const FLAG_6 = 0x40;
const FLAG_7 = 0x400;
 
function show_flags ($decimal) {
  if ($decimal & FLAG_1) {
    echo "Flag 1 included.<br>\n";
  }
  if ($decimal & FLAG_2) {
    echo "Flag 2 included.<br>\n";
  }
  if ($decimal & FLAG_3) {
    echo "Flag 3 included.<br>\n";
  }
  if ($decimal & FLAG_4) {
    echo "Flag 3 included.<br>\n";
  }
  if ($decimal & FLAG_5) {
    echo "Flag 3 included.<br>\n";
  }
  if ($decimal & FLAG_6) {
    echo "Flag 3 included.<br>\n";
  }
  if ($decimal & FLAG_7) {
    echo "Flag 3 included.<br>\n";
  }
}

show_flags($decimal);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, none of the flags are set in your `$decimal` so it is expected to print nothing. Even if you did set those flags, let say by adding `0xfff` to `$decimal`, it still won't print anything because the number is too large to be stored as an `int`, so it is stored as a `float`, which has limited precision. You can see this with `var_dump()`

```
$decimal = 613090029426844e18; // doesn't work
$decimal2 = 64; //works
var_dump($decimal);
var_dump($decimal2);
```

Output:

```
float(6.13090029426844E+32)
int(64)
```

A floating point number only stores the most significant digits (roughly 14 digits), any digit in the lower significant places are inevitably discarded.

```
$decimal3 = 613090029426844e18 + 0xfff;
```

Output:

```
float(6.13090029426844E+32)
```

So you won't be able to use the lower significant digits in a large number. You may want to take a look at `BigInterger` class [Is there a BigInteger class in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427020/is-there-a-biginteger-class-in-php)

Comment: Do I understand it the right way... If I use a biginteger class the above code would work because it's an integer and not a float anymore?

Comment: Yes. You have to refractor your code to use the dedicated BigInteger methods.