# how do I replace the content of a key in my json and save back on shopware 6.5 using php

Tags: php, json, shopware

I am working on a shopware project that requires me setup a json of all orders that is processed.

the json is stored in a directory which I have gotten out and passed to a variable **$fil**.

```php
$filer =  $order1->getOrderNumber() . '_' . $country2->getIso() . '.json';
$fil = __DIR__ . '/' . $filer;

$file_contents = file_get_contents($fil);
```

The gotten json stored in variable **$fil** is then passed to variable $jsonData

```php
$jsonData = $fil;
```

I am trying to replace the value of a key as below by decoding the JSON into an associative array

```php
$data = json_decode($jsonData, true);
```

The key to be replaced is as below (trying to replace ID)

```php
$data['entity']['payments'][0]['state']['id'] = $logMessageId;
```

I then try to save it back in variable **modifiedJsonData** and replace back to directory

```php
$modifiedJsonData = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

file_put_contents($fil, $modifiedJsonData);
```

it seemed to work partially but not fully, instead of replacing the (ID) alone

as here :     `$data['entity']['payments'][0]['state']['id']`

its replaces all the content of the json as below, the json content is supposed to be more than the below:

```json
{
    "entity": {
        "payments": [
            {
                "state": {
                    "id": #####
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Please help, what could I be doing wrong

Comment: $fil is the pathname of the json file, not the contents of it. this turns $data to NULL and then you are creating the contents as you finally see it. so just a small bug, resulting from not verifying preconditions or in this case not using JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR with json_decode();, Cf. https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.jsonexception.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the correct JSON Text in $jsonData and use two flags when you decode your JSON with json_decode(), the first always, the second more specifically in your current scenario:

1. [`JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php#constant.json-throw-on-error)
2. [`JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php#constant.json-bigint-as-string)

Example:

```php
$data = json_decode($jsonData, true, flags: JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR | JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);
```

(since PHP 8.0)

```php
$data = json_decode($jsonData, true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR | JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);
```

(since PHP 7.3)

### `JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR`

The reason why you only see the JSON for `$data['entity']['payments'][0]['state']['id']` is, because the `$data = json_decode(...)` operation returned `null` because the parsing failed. Using the `JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR` will turn any error into an exception, making this more visible because it stops the script on error.

This prevents you to search the error in later output.

> Throws [JsonException](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.jsonexception.php) if an error occurs instead of setting the global error state that is retrieved with [json_last_error()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) and [json_last_error_msg()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php). `JSON_PARTIAL_OUTPUT_ON_ERROR` takes precedence over `JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR`. Available as of PHP 7.3.0. *(PHP Manual)*

### `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING`

> Decodes large integers as their original string value. *(PHP Manual)*

BIGINT is referring to [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) (ECMA 262), a Javascript number value type for very large (negative and positive) integer numbers, json_decode() can easily loose precision with ([3v4l.org demo](https://3v4l.org/jDN8Y)):

```php
var_dump(json_decode('4599999999999999999999999999999999'));
var_dump(json_decode('4599999999999999999999999999999999', true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING));
```

```
float(4.6E+33)
string(34) "4599999999999999999999999999999999"
```

---

- Cf. [Q&A *"Is there a BigInteger class in PHP?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4427020/367456)
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.jsonexception.php

Comment: Thanks @hakre it seems there is a syntax error from what you out out. I work with php 8

Comment: Uncaught PHP Exception JsonException: "Syntax error"

Comment: 8.2 I mean is the php version

Comment: That's the JSON Exception, and this is by intention. It tells you already that the json_decode() operation failed, or worded differently: Parsing the JSON Text fails because there is a _syntax error_ "in the json". And sorry, I was AFK and quickly posted beforehand, so the answer might fall a little short with explanation. You also need to fix the bug beforehand assigning the wrong data to `$jsonData = $fil;`, from what I could see it must be `$jsonData = $file_contents;`.

Comment: yea, I found out that the previous data type I was trying to convert from was integer and while the new data come in was a string (large string) so I then introduced  $data = json_decode($jsonData, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);

Comment: You should keep the JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR flag in, because in case of any JSON parse error, the program does not continue so you can more easily learn about the actual error.

Answer (score 0):

I was also able to find away around it by:

```
<?php
    $data = json_decode($jsonData, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);
    $data['entity']['payments'][0]['state']['id'] = $logMessageId;
    $modifiedJsonData = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    $existingData = json_decode(file_get_contents($fil), true);
    $existingData['entity']['payments'][0]['state']['id'] = $data['entity']['payments'][0]['state']['id'];
    $updatedJsonData = json_encode($existingData, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    file_put_contents($fil, $updatedJsonData);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).