Different result in JS & PHP because of different integer range
<script>
function hs(e, n) {
    return e * n % e;
}
alert(hs(1752865668, 1716717484170));
//result:  1752622684 
</script>

<?php
function hs($e, $n) {
    return $e * $n % $e;
}
echo hs(1752865668, 1716717484170);
//result: 386969652
?>

Both results are different because of their different 53-bit & 32-bit integer range. How can I have the same result that JS calculated in PHP in this senario? (Without using GMP: GNU Multiple Precision) (Using PHP 8+)
In short: I need the PHP code snippet that exactly shows the same result as JS.
Thank you!

Note that the PHP version produces a warning about precision, in all currently supported versions: https://3v4l.org/coHlk

Maybe this will help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427020/is-there-a-biginteger-class-in-php

Actually, both results are wrong. The real result should be zero. See: https://3v4l.org/EATS5

Yes, both results are wrong. But, for some reason, I need to get the exact same result (even though it is wrong) that JS generated in PHP.

Emulating an error in one language in another language is never easy, and needs to be checked every time one of the languages is updated in any way. I would advice not to go down this route.

Well, you're right. Emulating an error in one language in another language is never easy and weird too, let me pass it to the PHP from JS. Can't find any better way than this, I have no choice left as the API server requires that.

Yes, sometimes we need to do weird things to get something working.  Also note that if you're using a client browser to run the Javascript that results may vary. Nowadays almost everything is Blink/WebKit, but there are exceptions.

function hs($e, $n) {
    return bcmod(sprintf('%f', $e * $n), $e);
}

This code gives me the same result, it needs the BCMath extension.

Explanation: Firstly, I found the following facts
BigInt(1752865668 * 1716717484170)      = 3009175139656926232576
1716717484169 * 1752865668 + 1752622684 = 3009175139656926232576

But the precise result should be 3009175139656926475560, so I realized that JavaScript may perform a modulo operation on a double floating number.
But PHP always converts the operands to integers. However the result of $e * $n here has exceeded the range of 64-bit integer, so another way of calculation is needed. Coincidentally, the BCMath extension meets the criteria. The extension requires operands to be strings in integer form, while sprintf converts floating numbers to their integral representations.

Can you explain your result?

@KIKOSoftware of course.

@Alo I agree it's epic, and I upvoted, but I still feel that this is a way to create a future bug. I other words: This code is fragile. Perhaps you can build some kind of warning system into your code that warns you when this doesn't emulate Javascript correctly anymore? At least then you have a head start trying to find the problem, years from now.

Yes, the code is fragile but it does exactly what I needed. The purpose of getting that is to post as a hash/token in a 3rd party API system that verifies the value (maybe a nodejs server), nothing except that the wrong result which was generated by JS is accepted. As long as that is not my system, I'm safe. I'm handling the response nicely. Sometimes, this kind of thing improves the security layer of an API system as they are harder to emulate. I have executed the code 3,00,000+ times till now with a 0 failure! Seems like promising! The wrong JS calculation is the correct token of the API!
